# I want to add showSnackBar to feedback user for this case

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, logic

> This is my onSavedChange func for user Information updating. also where do i need to add toast/snackbar, i cannot figure it out please help.

```
void onSavedChange() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      return;
    } else {
      try {
        loadingController.add(true);
        final response = await userApi.changeUserInformation(
          newEmail: textEditingControllerEmail.text.trim(),
          newFirstName: textEditingControllerFirstName.text.trim(),
          newLastName: textEditingControllerLastName.text.trim(),
        );
        printMe("response:$response");
        await LocalStorage.saveUserData(firstName: response.firstName, lastName:  response.lastName, email: response.email );
        AppConstant.FIRST_NAME = await LocalStorage.read(key: LocalStorage.FIRSTNAME);
        AppConstant.LAST_NAME = await LocalStorage.read(key: LocalStorage.LAST_NAME);
        AppConstant.USER_EMAIL = await LocalStorage.read(key: LocalStorage.UER_EMAIL_KEY);
        // printMe("data1 is ${AppConstant.FIRST_NAME}");
        // printMe("data2 is ${AppConstant.LAST_NAME}");
        // printMe("data3 is ${ AppConstant.USER_EMAIL}");
        bool? isLoading = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage(startPageIndex: 4, )));
        if (isLoading != null) {
          loadingController.add(isLoading);
        }
      }
      catch (error) {
        isLoading.add(false);
        UIHelper.showErrorMessageDialog(error, context);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there better to do this code

Comment: You can add snackbar before `bool? isLoading = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage(startPageIndex: 4, )));`.